# Github Actions CICD to build a SQL Server container fails but will work Locally

Tags: sql-server, bash, docker, dockerfile

I started working on Github actions to build some sample containers instead of doing my builds locally. Less reliance on my machines, etc.  It seems though that building and pushing on my MAC works, but creating an Action to do it will fail.

When doing tests locally, I did make sure I have an updated Dockerfile to ensure that everything is built as needed correctly, but part of me is thinking it is related to the OS building with the Github action, but I am trying to understand it more.

The error I get is:

> Error: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started"     && /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /a:Import /tsn:. /tdn:${DBNAME} /tu:sa /tp:$SA_PASSWORD /sf:/tmp/db.bacpac     && rm /tmp/db.bacpac     && pkill sqlservr]: exit code: 1

My workflow action is:

```
name: Docker Image CI MSSQL

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 6 * * *'
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      -
        name: Prepare Variables
        id: prepare
        run: |
          DOCKER_IMAGE=fallenreaper/eve-mssql
          VERSION=$(date -u +'%Y%m%d') 
          
          if [ "${{ github.event_name }}" = "schedule" ]; then
            VERSION=nightly
          fi
          TAGS="${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${VERSION}"
          if [[ $VERSION =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
            TAGS="$TAGS --tag ${DOCKER_IMAGE}:latest"
          fi
          
          echo ::set-output name=docker_image::${DOCKER_IMAGE}
          echo ::set-output name=version::${VERSION}
          echo ::set-output name=tags::${TAGS}
        
      -
        name: Login to DockerHub
        if: success() && github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      - 
        name: Docker Build & Push
        if: success() && github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{steps.prepare.outputs.tags}}
          context: mssql/.
```

So i was thinking this would work.  The Dockerfile I am building uses `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest` which I figured would work.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Password123!
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
ARG DBNAME=evesde

EXPOSE 1433

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install unzip -y
RUN wget -progress=bar:force -q -O sqlpackage.zip https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2165213 \
    && unzip -qq sqlpackage.zip -d /opt/sqlpackage \
    && chmod +x /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage

RUN wget -o /tmp/db.bacpac https://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/dump/mssql-latest.bacpac

RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" \
    && /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /a:Import /tsn:. /tdn:${DBNAME} /tu:sa /tp:$SA_PASSWORD /sf:/tmp/db.bacpac \
    && rm /tmp/db.bacpac \
    && pkill sqlservr
```

*EDIT* As I keep reading various documents, I am trying to understand and test various methods to see if i can spawn a build.  I was thinking that simulating a MAC might be useful, so i had also attempted to use the action: `runs-on: macos:latest` to see if that would solve it, but i havent seen gains as the run `docker-login-action@v1` will fail.

Comment: _executor failed_ ... why did it fail? You need to find a log file that tells you why

Comment: Can I suggest you take the divide and conquer approach. Don't run a huge ream of inline code and expect it to work. Does just `( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & )` work? Does just `( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started"` work? Because it only takes one character to be wrong for any piece of that bash to stop working.

Comment: The issue was not the sqlservr being up, it was the sqlpackage having malformed inputs as it was failing to wget the bacpac to /tmp correctly.   It was getting the file, but the file was not complete, inferring that wget was not completely getting the file.  When changing around some parameters on the otherhand, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking Through each line item I ended up the the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Password123!
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
ENV DBNAME=evesde

EXPOSE 1433

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install unzip -y
RUN wget -progress=bar:force -q -O sqlpackage.zip https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2165213 \
    && unzip -qq sqlpackage.zip -d /opt/sqlpackage \
    && chmod +x /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage

RUN wget -progress=bar:force -q -O /mssql-latest.bacpac https://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/dump/mssql-latest.bacpac

RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" \
    && /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /a:Import /tsn:. /tdn:$DBNAME /tu:sa /tp:$SA_PASSWORD /sf:/mssql-latest.bacpac \
    && pkill sqlservr
    
#Cleanup of created bulk files no longer needed.
RUN rm mssql-latest.bacpac sqlpackage.zip
```

The Main difference is where the bacpac file is stored.  It seemed there were hiccups when creating that file.  After adjusting the location, and breaking apart the import list, it seemed to work.

Notes:  When the file was created in TMP, it seemed to be partially created, and so it was recognizing the existing file but it was corrupt.  Not sure if there were size limits, but it was an observation.  Putting it in the / directory of the build gave me the access and complete file so i needed to adjust the /sf reference.

Lastly because there were hanging files which no longer were needed, I found it best to just do a little cleanup by deleting both the sqlpackage and bacpac files.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to investigate `grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" &&`

Maybe this fails, because you start `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr` then immediately check that it started. In most cases it takes few seconds to start.

To test if my thesis is correct.Suggesting to insert few `sleep 10` or `timeout` commands in strategic places.

Comment: I am looking at this line.  If the purpose is that the sqlserver is going to be detached, and i am looking for the "has started" so I know to continue into the next thing, how would that work if i am grepping that other detached process?  Would it be something like:   `(/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) && sleep 10 | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && ...`?

Comment: Let me see if i can break it into more lines instead of it being jammed into 1.

Comment: Update:  This doesnt work.  Kind of weird though, because this file works perfectly on my host machine etc, so im curious as to what the problem is with this and running it as a worker.

Comment: When running process in the background `(/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & )` it is always successful and the next command will run immediately and not wait (obviously `grep` will fail). Suggesting to timeout with `timeout` command on an anticipated log file or on connection test query.

Comment: Youre good. Already found the answer. :)

Comment: Glad I can assist, please vote the answer.